# Combine 2 lists into 1 list with tuple elements

Tags: python

May I know the python built-in function to do the following? That is, combine 2 lists into 1 list such that the elements of each list is used to form a tuple element in the new list. Thank you.

```
>>> a = ['1','2','3']
>>> b = ['x','y','z']
>>> c = []
>>> for i, val in enumerate(a):
    c.append( (i, b[i]) )
>>> c
[(0, 'x'), (1, 'y'), (2, 'z')]
>>>
```

Comment: `print(list(zip(a, b)))` ?

Comment: Your example code forms a list of tuples where the first element is an INDEX of an item from the first list, not the item itself. Is this what you intended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `zip`:

```
>>> list(zip(a,b))
[('1', 'x'), ('2', 'y'), ('3', 'z')]
```